# Gameboy-like keys and D-Pad for Android

Tags: android, usb, arduino, gameboy

I wanted to make an RPG for Android 2.3 Mobile Phone and thought that the good old Gameboy had the perfect format for such games. So I want to build a "Case" with a D-Pad and a few keys and connect them with the Android Device over USB. I don't want Bluetooth, because it needs to much energy. I thought about giving the Case its own Battery Cell and maybe loading the Android Device with it. So my Question is:

How can I access the Keys of this Case from the Android Device?

Answer (score 5):

You might consider the [Android Open Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html).

Even if you don't want to buy the ADK, the above link has information that will be useful to you in developing an interface to your accessory. In particular, the section on [implementing the accessory protocol](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html#accessory-protocol) and the following section on how the ADK implements the protocol should prove informative. In addition, you'll probably want to look at the [USB Accessory link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html) which contains [a section concerning communication with an accessory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html#communicating-a).

Comment: Thanks, but I  don't want to buy the ADK because I have an Arduino Board with an Atmega 168 already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use USB on devices that have a host USB port unfortunately, not many devices have this. Your other options are bluetooth or wifi both can be accomplished in a multitude of ways. If you Google Arduino + Android I believe you will find examples of people connecting hardware to Android devices via Arduino. This is not the only way to do it, just an example of one way you could do it.

Android USB documentation
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html

EDIT
You, could I suppose, use Arduino as the USB host also and use accessory mode on the Android end. In any case this none of these options are incredibly straightforward and you will need to do a lot of research to accomplish what you are envisioning.

Comment: Thank you, but like I said, my Android Device has Version 2.3 which doesn't support the USB Host Mode. The other people who showed how they connected Arduino and Android all used wireless connections or the Android ADK. But I had to buy the ADK but I already have an Arduino so I don't want to by the ADK. Instead of that I want to use the Arduino with the Atmega 168 I already own.